# i18n on a variable

Tags: php, variables, internationalization

I would like to know if I can use a gt function on a variable with php?

eg. : `echo _($var);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think gettext will recognize a variable since it scans the source code.  If you want to include variables in a string, it's better to use

```
sprintf()
```

For example

```
echo sprintf(_("There are %d results!"), $numResults);
```

In gettext, the translator will see

```
There are %d results!
```

so therefore it can easily be translated as long as he/she knows that %d is a variable. When the script gets executed, gettext will first replace the translation, and then sprintf will insert the variable $numResults. Good luck! I just got done internationalizing my site.

Comment: In this specific case it should be `sprintf(ngettext("There is %d result!", "There are %d results!", $numResults), $numResults)`.

Comment: I doubt if the question was about substitution (which is out of question), but rather than having a whole string retrieved from the other datasource (e.g. database). And, btw, gettext doesn't really scan the source, `xgettext` does and you aren't strictly obliged to use `xgettext` at all.

Comment: Lukáš Lalinský, right, this is how you know Slavic language speaker ;-) We care about plural forms.

Comment: yea, the overall question is kinda vague too

Comment: I'm open to any kind of answers, just looking for the best way to use i18n on variables.

Answer (score 5):

Feel free to. But you need to make sure the possible contents of the variable makes it into `.po`/`.mo` files. (one of the ways to do assure it is to create a dummy file never processed except for by `xgettext`, containing `_("translate me");` expressions).